# How can I pass this javascript game score into a Django Model?

Tags: javascript, python, django, post, backend

right now i need to make a website that has his own games. Currently everything is working fine, but I need to know how I can store the high score then to a django model.

My Idea is a hidden POST form, which gets triggered automatically(currently even manual would be enough), and then it just submits the integer stored in a JavaScript variable via the POST form to the model.

I will provide you with my current Code snippets, so you will know how far I am and how I am approaching.

```
views.py

def loadGame(request, slug):
    game = Game.objects.get(slug=slug)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        pass
    
    return render(request, 'main/game-detail.html', {
        'game': game
    })
```

my hidden form in the template

```
<form action="/games/{{ game.slug }}" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}        
        <button type="submit" hidden>Upload your highscore to the Leaderboard?</button>
    </form>
```

models.py model for the leaderboard

```
class Ranking(models.Model):
    player = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    game_overall_score = models.IntegerField(null=True)
```

```
var score = 0;
...
if (pipes[i].hits(bird)) {
      score = 0;
      pipes = [];
      return;
    }
...
if (frameCount % 5 == 0) {
    score++;
  }
```

I actually don't even know where to start. I looked up multiple approaches with jQuery or AJAX, but no one had the same situation like me, I really need to store only one single integer, the user will be then assigned automatically

Comment: why do you need a form to send a HTTP request to the server, read the JavaScript Fetch protocol, or use jQuery Ajax calls

Answer (score 0):

I think you're overthinking this. I avoid submitting form-data whenever possible. Lean on JQuery and its simple event handling. I'm not sure how you're getting the username, but I just put a field in there for it. Otherwise, just grab the variable.

```html
<!--HTML -->
<input type="text" id="player-name">
<button id="submit-score">Upload your score</button>

<!--Javascript-->
<script>

var score = 0
// Your score counting stuff
$("#submit-score").on("click", function(){
    data={}
    data['game_overall_score'] = score
    data['player'] = $("#player-name").val()
    $.ajax({
        url: "...",
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json",
        data: JSON.stringify(data),,
        success: function(){
            //do whaterever you want here
        }
    })
})
</script>
```